BadRequestError during creating embedding for Azure AI search. Error: code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "'$.input' is invalid}}
New to Azure. Trying to create embeddings for Azure AI Search  following the code here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/basic-vector-workflow/azure-search-vector-python-sample.ipynb
On Jupyter notebook, My Python code looks like
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, get_bearer_token_provider


openai_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
token_provider = get_bearer_token_provider(openai_credential, "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

output_path = os.path.join('output', 'docVectors.json')

client = AzureOpenAI(
    api_version=azure_openai_api_version,
    azure_endpoint=azure_openai_endpoint,
    api_key=azure_openai_key,
    azure_deployment=azure_openai_embedding_deployment,
    azure_ad_token_provider=token_provider if not azure_openai_key else None
)

# Generate Document Embeddings using OpenAI Ada 002
# Read the text-sample.json
path = os.path.join('data', 'worthiness_with_result.json')
with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    input_data = json.load(file)

def filter_empty_strings(data):
    return [item for item in data if item]

results = filter_empty_strings([item['result'] for item in input_data])
result_response = client.embeddings.create(input=results,model=azure_openai_embedding_model, dimensions=azure_openai_embedding_dimensions)
result_embeddings = [item['embedding'] for item in result_response['data']]


.....

# Generate embeddings for title and content fields
for i, item in enumerate(input_data):
    item['resultVector'] = result_embeddings[i]
    ....


# Output embeddings to docVectors.json file
output_directory = os.path.dirname(output_path)
if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
    os.makedirs(output_directory)
with open(output_path, "w") as f:
    json.dump(input_data, f)

where :
azure_openai_embedding_deployment= embedding_test
azure_openai_embedding_model= text-embedding-ada-002
azure_openai_api_version= 2023-03-15-preview

With the code above, I am getting error:
BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "'$.input' is invalid. Please check the API reference: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

Details on the error:
BadRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 28
     25     return [item for item in data if item]
     27 results = filter_empty_strings([item['result'] for item in input_data])
---> 28 result_response = client.embeddings.create(input=results, model=azure_openai_embedding_model, dimensions=azure_openai_embedding_dimensions)

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/resources/embeddings.py:114, in Embeddings.create(self, input, model, dimensions, encoding_format, user, extra_headers, extra_query, extra_body, timeout)
    108         embedding.embedding = np.frombuffer(  # type: ignore[no-untyped-call]
    109             base64.b64decode(data), dtype="float32"
    110         ).tolist()
    112     return obj
--> 114 return self._post(
    115     "/embeddings",
    116     body=maybe_transform(params, embedding_create_params.EmbeddingCreateParams),
    117     options=make_request_options(
    118         extra_headers=extra_headers,
    119         extra_query=extra_query,
    120         extra_body=extra_body,
    121         timeout=timeout,
    122         post_parser=parser,
    123     ),
    124     cast_to=CreateEmbeddingResponse,
    125 )

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py:1260, in SyncAPIClient.post(self, path, cast_to, body, options, files, stream, stream_cls)
   1246 def post(
   1247     self,
   1248     path: str,
   (...)
   1255     stream_cls: type[_StreamT] | None = None,
   1256 ) -> ResponseT | _StreamT:
   1257     opts = FinalRequestOptions.construct(
   1258         method="post", url=path, json_data=body, files=to_httpx_files(files), **options
   1259     )
-> 1260     return cast(ResponseT, self.request(cast_to, opts, stream=stream, stream_cls=stream_cls))

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py:937, in SyncAPIClient.request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
    928 def request(
    929     self,
    930     cast_to: Type[ResponseT],
   (...)
    935     stream_cls: type[_StreamT] | None = None,
    936 ) -> ResponseT | _StreamT:
--> 937     return self._request(
    938         cast_to=cast_to,
    939         options=options,
    940         stream=stream,
    941         stream_cls=stream_cls,
    942         remaining_retries=remaining_retries,
    943     )

File /opt/homebrew/anaconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py:1041, in SyncAPIClient._request(self, cast_to, options, remaining_retries, stream, stream_cls)
   1038         err.response.read()
   1040     log.debug("Re-raising status error")
-> 1041     raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
   1043 return self._process_response(
   1044     cast_to=cast_to,
   1045     options=options,
   (...)
   1049     retries_taken=options.get_max_retries(self.max_retries) - retries,
   1050 )

BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': "'$.input' is invalid. Please check the API reference: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference.", 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': None}}

I am getting hard time understanding what is this error for. Any clue?
If I print the "results", it looks like :
[-5759.12, -2997.68, 3498.0748000000003, 4368.7612, 913.6112, 24922.718, 16120.722, 1560.622, 19102.6684, 7897.2512, 4.1262958737372343e-13, 41062.5401, 20809.3396, 861.7709, 5764.752, 2237.2804, 18778.1712, 779.211, 15279.093200000001, 5373.621, 2065.7306, 50715.734300000004, 2330.3348, 1066.9288, 1518.1474, 9842.0912, 7679.6024, 12653.202, 7892.9774, 805.6532, 8786.36, 26726.585600000002, 198.6692, 32071.5668, 203005.66, 17249.1272, 3572.5712000000003 ...... ]


Add you sample input data.

Provided solution below. Is it working for you?

As error says the input is invalid, the results input you given
[-5759.12, -2997.68, 3498.0748000000003, 4368.7612, 913.6112, 24922.718, 16120.722, 1560.622, 19102.6684, 7897.2512, 4.1262958737372343e-13, 41062.5401, 20809.3396, 861.7709, 5764.752, 2237.2804, 18778.1712, 779.211, 15279.093200000001, 5373.621, 2065.7306, 50715.734300000004, 2330.3348, 1066.9288, 1518.1474, 9842.0912, 7679.6024, 12653.202, 7892.9774, 805.6532, 8786.36, 26726.585600000002, 198.6692, 32071.5668, 203005.66, 17249.1272, 3572.5712000000003 ...... ]
is numerical which is not the required input to embedding model.
You need to pass the list of text inputs to generate embedding.
Below is the sample example.
results  = ["Hi how are you?"]
result_response  =  client.embeddings.create(input=results,model="text-embedding-ada-002")
result_embeddings  = [item.embedding  for  item  in  result_response.data]
result_embeddings

Output:
[[-0.014039497, 0.009754552, 0.0011114076, -0.04075739, -0.026491044, 0.022949664, -0.012149081, -0.012817028, -0.011304694, -0.013358947, 0.01926965, ....]]
So, alter you filter_empty_strings function to check both for empty items and for the type of each item being a string
def filter_empty_strings(data):
    return [item for item in data if isinstance(item, str) and item]

